# POWER BI - RLS - Analyze in Excel connection

Tags: excel, powerbi

I am now experimenting with "**Analyze in Excel**" feature in **POWER BI**. **I would like to use the RLS to load RLS filtered table** (**NOT** to actually analyze the OLAP Cube with pivot table)

I have **successfully** set up row level security using this Table filter DAX expression:

```
SEARCH( userprincipalname(), [Email], 1, 0 ) > 0
```

After creating a dummy **Measure=1** I was able to double click ("drill through") the Pivot table (by double clicking on the measure value in the pivot table). This gave me a linked table with the following command text:

```
DRILLTHROUGH MAXROWS 1000
SELECT FROM [Model] WHERE
(([Measures].[Measure],[Table1].[email].&[xxx@xxx.xxx],[Table1].[ID].&[4], 
[Table1].[X].&[654]))
```

After removing the filter part =>

```
DRILLTHROUGH MAXROWS 1000
SELECT FROM [Model]
WHERE (([Measures].[Measure]))
```

=> I was able to get a linked table with all the columns and rows. Also the **RLS** works: when I refresh from a different account I see only the allowed/limited rows. - Amazing! (Using Office 365, signed-in account)

This is how to get the linked table:
[double click on measure in OLAP Pivot in Analyze in Excel file from POWER BI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUB20.gif)

**My goal was to set up a linked EXCEL table with working RLS (without using MS SQL server or other) - this seems to work now!**

My questions are:

1. **Will the connection obtained via "Analyze in Excel" be working PERMANENTLY or is it only TEMPORARY?**
2. **Can I modify the "SQL" command text even more to return the whole table/data set? Something like "Select * From ... " - (of course while respecting the RLS)**
3. **Is this approach reliable? Can you think of any downsides?**
4. **Could someone exploit the connection to ignore the RLS?**

Warm regards.
Jakub